# Do I need to stop or pause a container before I export a volume?

Tags: container, cgroups, podman

To avoid an inconsistent volume backup, I pause (or outright stop) a container before I copy the contents of the volume. Is this still necessary when backing up containers via `podman volume export`, or does podman transparently freeze any container using the exported volume behind the scenes?

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2168256 infer what you must

Comment: @MarcusMüller Wow. Guess I'll continue pausing the container regardless. I'll leave this question open since (I assume) this particular cve will eventually get patched. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Related PR https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/17528